# SQLite. Column constraint CHECK doesn't work with an INTEGER column

Tags: sqlite, constraints

I tested the following cases.

CHECK is applied to an INTEGER column. It doesn't work.

```
sqlite> CREATE TABLE log (_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, timestamp INTEGER NOT NULL, message TEXT NOT NULL, status INTEGER NOT NULL CHECK (status IN (1, 0));
Error: near ";": syntax error
```

CHECK is applied to a TEXT column. It works.

```
sqlite> CREATE TABLE log (_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, timestamp INTEGER NOT NULL, message TEXT NOT NULL CHECK (message IN ('Bad', 'OK')), status INTEGER NOT NULL);
sqlite> insert into log values (3, 11111, 'OK', 1); 
sqlite> select * from log;
3|11111|OK|1
sqlite> insert into log values (3, 11111, 'dsvsdvOK', 1); 
Error: constraint failed
```

Both cases should work if I understand the documentation correctly.

[column-constraint](http://www.sqlite.org/syntaxdiagrams.html#column-constraint)

[expr](http://www.sqlite.org/syntaxdiagrams.html#expr)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first CREATE TABLE statement has three opening but only two closing parentheses.